# How to put the data from mssql into a list box? PHP

Tags: php, html, sql-server-2008

```
if (!$conn)
  {exit("Connection Failed: " . $conn);}

   $sql_exp = "select * from dbo.PC inner join dbo.FA_PC on dbo.PC.PCID = dbo.FA_PC.PCID WHERE UserID is NOT NULL order by dbo.fa_pc.PCID"; 
   $sql_exp1= "select * from dbo.users inner join dbo.FA_PC on dbo.users.UserID = dbo.FA_PC.UserID order by dbo.fa_pc.PCID";
   $sql_exp2 = "SELECT * FROM dbo.FA_PC WHERE FA_TypeID is NOT NULL ORDER BY PCID"; 
   $rs = $conn->Execute($sql_exp);
    $rs1 = $conn->Execute($sql_exp1);
   $rs2 = $conn->Execute($sql_exp2);
   echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='0' id='rounded-corner'><tr><th>Desktop Number</th><th>Employee</th><th><p align=left>Fixed Asset Accountability</p></th></tr>";
   while (!$rs->EOF) {
       set_time_limit(0);
       echo "<td>CP # <br>".$rs->Fields("PC_Number")."</td>";   
       echo "<td>".$rs1->Fields("EmployeeName")."</td>";    
       echo "<td>".$rs2->Fields("FA_TypeID")."</td><tr>";   

      $rs->MoveNext();
      $rs1->MoveNext();
   }
   echo "</table>";   
   $rs->Close();
       ?>
```

how could i put $rs->Fields("PC_Number") into a list box which will be submitted into new form

Answer (score 0):

If `$rs->Fields("PC_Number")` is not an array you can use this.. If its an array you have to use looping statements...This will give you a list box containing only one option..

```
<select>
   <option value="1"><?php echo $rs->Fields("PC_Number");?></option>
</select>
```

Comment: how could i call the data that the user picked from the list box to display it on another form?